# TableRow columns not aligned in the right

Tags: android, tableview, tablelayout, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I try to create an XML for remote control, but some TableRow columns move to right ( as it is shown in screenshot ). How can I fix it ?

[image]

And here is my XML code ( it is too big and I can not put it here ):
https://codeshare.io/aVkyxR

As you see from image all rows except the 2-nd one and last four lines are moved to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in this way, hope that it will be useful for someone and will help to save a time:

https://codeshare.io/5OBeMN

Answer (score 0):

I think [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) should help you to build layout like that.